# Dynamically wrapping matching substrings in Vue components

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of words, such as:

```
["Foo","Bar"]
```

When presented with a string, I'd like to dynamically replace words found in the list with components. Given a string like this:

```
"Foo lorem ipsum dolor Bar."
```

The result would be:

```
<MyComponent :text="Foo"/> lorem ipsum dolor <MyComponent :text="Bar"/>.
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  props: ['word'],
  template: '<span class="my-component">{{word}}</span>'
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'Foo is the new Bar.',
      filters: new Set(['Foo', 'Bar'])
    }
  },
  computed: {
    tokens() {
      return this.text.match(/(?:\b|^).+?(?:\b|$)/g)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.my-component {
  color: #0095ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="token in tokens">
    <my-component v-if="filters.has(token)" :word="token"></my-component>
    <template v-else>{{ token }}</template>
   </template>
</div>
```

The idea is quite straightforward:

1. split the desired string into tokens
2. for each token, verify if it is in word list:

   - if so, render it with your component
   - otherwise, render it as default

This will do literally what you want :)

NOTE: the use of `template` helps having a clean HTML output, without useless `div` or `span` elements.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for. One quick addition--how would you recommend handling recursive cases, such as ['Foo', "Foo Bar', 'Bar'] => "Foo Bar is new" ?

Comment: The issue is totally different in that case. You could maybe take advantage of [`string.includes`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/includes) and remove any substring that has already been processed?

Comment: Thank you, I'll consider that.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) is the only thing needed for this.

```js
Vue.component('mycomponent', {
  props: ['word'],
  template: '<div> Word is {{word}} </div>'
})


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function(){
    return{
        text: 'Foo lorem ipsum dolor Bar',
      selectedWords: ['Foo', 'Bar']
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" >
  <div v-for="item in text.split(' ')">
    <div v-if="selectedWords.includes(item)">
      <mycomponent
            :key="item"
            :word="item">
      </mycomponent>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tehsurfer/d4zLcrj8/2/)

## Explanation

I've passed `word` as a [`prop`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) to `mycomponent`. Then used the shorthand for [`v-bind:`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) which is `:` to bind `item` to `word`

*Disclaimer*: I also am learning Vue XD

Comment: Although v-for is the right direction, I don't think that would give me the behavior (e.g. "lorem ipsum dolor" unwrapped) I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah yes you're right Jasper, sorry when I read the question I saw 'the list' and assumed there was only one

Comment: No worries at all!